# how to display Array Value using ng-repeat in ionic

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic and app development.
here is my code
**app.js**

```
 .controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.Users = [{
          name:"abdulla",
          city:"Korutla"
        },{
          name:"zulqarnain",
          city:"Hyderabad"
        },{
          name:"Hameen",
          city:"Karimnager"
        },{
          name:"yasir",
          city:"hyd"
        }];         
    })
```

**index.html**

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader">

          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in Users">
              {{Users.name}}
            </li>
          </ul>
</ion-content>
```

why it doesn't show me output

Comment: "Here is my code" "Why doesn't it work" is not a good way to ask for help. Articulate the problem you are having and what you have tried to do to resolve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the variable `Users` to `user`

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in Users">
              {{user.name}}
            </li>
          </ul>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: ooh, how this small mistake I can't recognize!.thank u .